# Prevent Email Going to Spam

Tags: email, postfix, spam, spf, dkim

I've set up my own server and I'm really struggling to stop any outgoing email go to spam.

I've used allaboutspam and mail-tester.com to test it and they both come back with perfect results. No issues with reverse lookup, dkim or spf records. As far as I'm aware, I'm not on any black lists.

Below is the SPF record I'm using. The record name is cornhillfarm.co.uk

```
v=spf1 ip4:95.138.166.68 +a +mx ~all
```

Here's a brief clip of the header sent to gmail from the account

```
Delivered-To: me@email.co.uk
Received: by 10.70.38.39 with SMTP id d7csp343605pdk;
        Mon, 1 Dec 2014 08:46:42 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.194.121.129 with SMTP id lk1mr30339186wjb.99.1417452401636;
        Mon, 01 Dec 2014 08:46:41 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <info@cornhillfarm.co.uk>
Received: from grid3.woodbridgemedia.co.uk (grid3.woodbridgemedia.co.uk. [95.138.166.68])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id xv5si30948234wjc.162.2014.12.01.08.46.40
        for <me@email.co.uk>;
        Mon, 01 Dec 2014 08:46:40 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of info@cornhillfarm.co.uk designates 95.138.166.68 as     permitted sender) client-ip=95.138.166.68;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of info@cornhillfarm.co.uk designates 95.138.166.68 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=info@cornhillfarm.co.uk;
   dkim=pass header.i=@cornhillfarm.co.uk
Received: from grid.woodbridgemedia.co.uk (grid3.woodbridgemedia.co.uk [127.0.0.1])
by grid3.woodbridgemedia.co.uk (Postfix) with ESMTPA id 32C32B4490
for <me@email.co.uk>; Mon,  1 Dec 2014 16:46:44 +0000 (UTC)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=cornhillfarm.co.uk;
s=default; t=1417452404;
bh=ARgAG5dpW0g4y11fXdXMWe/ZrWwUJlaCkCKhW45skOU=;
h=Date:From:To:Subject;
b=jMEbxoDGBpx5U9MGmvoQ11Xzf3SFy5EZbtS1j5uIysR9g/uc02vP/9anss7tUpKhn
 QAML+qYjGGo7CU9lfdQqtyxhYukWHoZysQsy2nIVm/uYzmQDbWFiiiOJopMqQdgnkm
 xArDQ7FucQgChsGF9g1iX1qyzpkMRGCbEJ1JFpOs=
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong here to try and get it out of the spam folder?

If you need any other information about my setup that I've missed, let me know and I'll send the relevant information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you saying Google marked this as spam despite the "Received-SPF: pass" results? Or am I misunderstanding the question? Remember, Google filters spam on content as well as headers/source.

Comment: That's correct, Google is still marking it as spam. I've tried different subjects and messages and it's still appearing to be filtered into spam. Any ideas?

Comment: @EEAA Not a duplicate of that question; it deals with _incoming_ spam.

Comment: @MichaelHampton as far as I see, the given header is from a mail sended by `grid3.woodbridgemedia.co.uk` sent to gmail.

Answer (score 0):

I went through and looked for obvious DNS issues and none were apparent. As far as I can tell it's an issue of IP reputation.

There are really only two good solutions to this:

1. Get added to mail server whitelists and/or warm up the address by putting legitimate traffic over it.
2. Use a smarthost/relay like Mandrill or Sendgrid. They're dirt cheap and make it easy to get past even the most stringent spam filters.

I'd recommend option 2 over option 1 for a SMB or similar.